# I want to dynamically generate a form based on the data passed into my functional component. Different data mens different forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-functional-component

In the following code i take in an Object.  I pull out the object keys that i would like to use as labels for the form.  I have written several different **for loops** that can create an array of const variables. My problem is building the **[idProps, idMeta]** variable to pass into my form. **[idProps, idMeta]** need to change for each form input **[{label}Props, {label}Meta]** The useField() is tricky. Any suggestions or reference some other code would be welcome.

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useField } from 'fielder';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import BrewFormGroup from '../FormComponents/BrewFormGroup';
import BrewButton from '../Buttons/BrewButtons';


function BrewFormComponent(props) {
console.log("row ===> ",props.data);

  // Variables and const 
  const data =props.data;
  console.log(data);
  const keys = Object.keys(data);
  const test = [];

  const createVars = ()=>{
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      const element = keys[i];
      test.push(element);

    }
  }
createVars();
  const [idProps, idMeta] = useField({
    name: 'id',
    initialValue: props.data.id,
  });

  //   ========== Functions ============

// const keys = HandleData.getObjectKeysprops2(data);
  const handleSubmit = useCallback((event) => {
    
  }, []);

  const changeLocation = () => {
    alert("Submit to local storage")
    console.log("Hobnob===> "+test[2]);
  }
  
  //   =============== Return ===================

  return (
        <Container><Row className="mb-2 justify-right">
      <Col></Col><Col><BrewButton
        variant="success"
        type="submit"
        onClick={changeLocation}
        value="Submit"></BrewButton></Col>
        </Row>
        <Form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <BrewFormGroup
              props={idProps}
              meta={idMeta}
              label="id"
              type="text"
            />
      </Form></Container>)
};

export default BrewFormComponent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think you can use other features of Formik to accomplish your goal. Instead of dynamically building fields with `useField`, you can instead map over your props in your output itself. Something like:

```
return (
      <Form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {Object.keys(props.data).map((key) => (
          <Field id={key} name={key} initialValue={props.data[key]} />
        )}
      </Form>
```

Comment: thanks i was able to pass data into <BrewFormGroup>  which is a component that is basically same as  <Field> and i dynamically build forms with different data sizes and keys.

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer solved your issue please mark it as accepted